# Определение координатной четверти фигуры

Tags: python

Всем привет, написал задачу на пайтоне:

**Задача:**

Определите, в какой координатной четверти расположен треугольник, образованный прямой, заданной уравнением y=ax+b, и осями координат.
Вот мой код:

```py
a = float(input("Введите коэффициент a: "))
b = float(input("Введите коэффициент b: "))

if a > 0 and b > 0:
    print("Треугольник находится в первой координатной четверти.")
elif a < 0 and b > 0:
    print("Треугольник находится во второй координатной четверти.")
elif a < 0 and b < 0:
    print("Треугольник находится в третьей координатной четверти.")
elif a > 0 and b < 0:
    print("Треугольник находится в четвертой координатной четверти.")
else:
    print("Точка пересечения находится на оси координат.")
```

Правильно сделал?

Comment: Неправильно. Первый же случай y=x+1.  Найдите точки пересечения прямой с осями координат.

Answer (score 2):

Для решения данной задачи следовало нарисовать графики функции `y = a * x + b`, чтобы убедиться что *треугольники*, образованные прямой и линиями координат будут находиться в таких квадрантах:

- `a > 0`:

  - `b > 0` : II квадрант
  - `b < 0` : IV квадрант
- `a < 0`:

  - `b > 0` : I квадрант
  - `b < 0` : III квадрант

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно, код можно упростить, убрав операторы `if`:

- сначала проверяем, существует ли треугольник, т.е. оба коэффициента отличаются от нуля, а значит, их произведение не равно нулю
- затем "вычисляем" квадрант, используя неявное преобразование `True -> 1, False -> 0`

```py
a = float(input("Введите коэффициент a: "))
b = float(input("Введите коэффициент b: "))

if a * b == 0:
    print("Треугольника не существует.")
else:
    s = ["в первой", "во второй", "в третьей", "в четвертой"][2 * (b < 0) + (a > 0)]    
    print(f"Треугольник находится {s} координатной четверти.")
```

Comment: Основное - что при нулевом `a` треугольник не существует